# How to properly set the spark driver maxresultssize for files compressed in parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I keep running into an issue with container sizing on spark.  I do not see any obvious problems with what I’m trying to accomplish.  Here are my settings:

```
5 machines, 
one master  
4 nodes.  

Each node has 61 G and 8 cores total.
```

And the spark settings:

```
spark.driver.memory 5g
spark.history.ui.port=18081

spark.executor.memory=39936mb
spark.executor.cores=7
spark.executor.instances=4

spark.master=yarn-client
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7168
```

My job keeps failing at the very end, and I’m not sure why.  Here are the logs right when it starts to show signs of failure:

```
17/05/16 19:57:51 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 3571812, boot = 17, init = 481752, finish = 3090043
17/05/16 19:57:52 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 200 non-empty blocks out of 200 blocks
17/05/16 19:57:52 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 5 remote fetches in 100 ms
17/05/16 19:57:59 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 6373, boot = -60752, init = 60758, finish = 6367
17/05/16 19:59:38 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 5.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 978)
17/05/16 19:59:38 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 21.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 994)
17/05/16 19:59:38 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
17/05/16 19:59:38 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
17/05/16 19:59:38 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
*17/05/16 19:59:38 ERROR datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Aborting task.*
```

….
Later on…

```
17/05/16 19:59:38 INFO hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 40,062,362
17/05/16 19:59:38 ERROR datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Aborting task.
```

….and then at the very end:

```
17/05/16 19:59:40 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
17/05/16 19:59:40 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
17/05/16 19:59:40 WARN python.PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
17/05/16 19:59:40 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

It seems like it is not a YARN exception - it is coming from spark.  And, it seems like it is having trouble writing the results to file.  So, I’m wondering what the issue might be.

If it is an issue at the driver, then I wonder if I should increase `spark.driver.memory`, but then again, it is already 5 g which is pretty high.

I also did not think I needed to increase `spark.driver.maxResultsSize`, which by default is 1g, because I looked at the files that have been outputted by this in the past, and they are 0.4 g compressed in parquet.

What settings should I change?

Comment: Anyway you could show your code and sample data? I'm more on the scala side of spark, but I use parquet extensively without really any trouble of this sort.

Comment: `driver.*` properties are not relevant here.

Comment: @zero323 can you please explain why?  And, does it have to do with the number of parittions, perhaps?

Comment: Because these are applicable for the driver. Writing Parquet file doesn't really involve driver.

Comment: Which settings affect the writing to parquet?

Comment: @zero323 I am open to any sggestions you might have

Comment: Since you're getting exceptions from the Python worker, you should first take a look at the plain Python code (RDDs, Python UDFs), not writes. My guess is you'll get the same error if replace writes with dummy `foreach`.

Comment: okay....i'm not totally sure what you mean by "if replace writes with dummy `foreach`".  
But anyway - which settings affect the writing to parquet?  (which, I assume is the issue - writing to parquet).